# split values while printing in a file

Tags: java, json, file, guava

I am printing a value in a file i need to split them onces the first content is finished leave some spaces and then print the next one

```
public class Test_Json {


    public static ArrayList<Object> ls1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public static ArrayList<Object> ls2 = new ArrayList<Object>();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;

        try {
            Gson g = new Gson();
            JsonElement jsonElement1 = parser.parse(new FileReader("D://sample1.json"));
            JsonElement jsonElement2 = parser.parse(new FileReader("D://sample2.json"));
            // System.out.println("Is the two JSON File Same: "+compareJson(jsonElement1,jsonElement2));
            if (!compareJson(jsonElement1, jsonElement2)) {
                Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
                }.getType();
                Map<String, Object> firstMap = g
                        .fromJson(jsonElement1, mapType);
                Map<String, Object> secondMap = g.fromJson(jsonElement2,
                        mapType);
                System.out.println(" The Two JSON Files Are Not the Same ");
                System.out.println(Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap));
                String s = Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap).toString();
                try{
                    fw = new FileWriter("D:\\output.txt");
                    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write(s);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("The Two JSON Are SAME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static boolean compareJson(JsonElement json1, JsonElement json2) {
        boolean isEqual = true;


        if (json1 != null && json2 != null) {


            if (json1.isJsonObject() && json2.isJsonObject()) {
                Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> ens1 = ((JsonObject) json1)
                        .entrySet();
                Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> ens2 = ((JsonObject) json2)
                        .entrySet();
                JsonObject json2obj = (JsonObject) json2;
                if (ens1 != null && ens2 != null
                        && (ens2.size() == ens1.size())) {

                    for (Entry<String, JsonElement> en : ens1) {
                        isEqual = isEqual
                                && compareJson(en.getValue(),
                                        json2obj.get(en.getKey()));
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else if (json1.isJsonArray() && json2.isJsonArray()) {
                JsonArray jarr1 = json1.getAsJsonArray();
                JsonArray jarr2 = json2.getAsJsonArray();
                if (jarr1.size() != jarr2.size()) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    int i = 0;

                    for (JsonElement je : jarr1) {
                        isEqual = isEqual && compareJson(je, jarr2.get(i));
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (isEqual) {
                        ls1.toArray();
                        ls2.toArray();
                        isEqual = ls1.containsAll(ls2);
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (json1.isJsonNull() && json2.isJsonNull()) {
                return true;
            }

            else if (json1.isJsonPrimitive() && json2.isJsonPrimitive()) {

                ls1.add(json1);
                ls2.add(json2);
                return true;
            }
            else if((json1.isJsonPrimitive() & json2.isJsonArray()) || (json2.isJsonPrimitive() && json1.isJsonArray())){
                return false;
            }
        } else if (json1 == null && json2 == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return isEqual;
    }
}
```

Map.difference method gets the difference form the two file and prints them. I need to first print first file difference and then leave some lines of space and print the next file difference. This i am doing to show the contents seperately. At present it is displaying without any spaces so identifying is difficult.

I need something like this
Difference values in first file:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

Difference in second file:

```
{
    "id": 14,
    "name": "A green door bell",
    "price": 127.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

The method entriesOnlyOnLeft() and entriesOnlyOnRight() is not displaying the differece as the key should be different but here the key are same

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @shmosel once the differenceis found between the two json file that i am having there has to be some kind of seperation so that i can identify the first value and second value. At present the difference is getting printed as a whole to the file

Comment: You mean you want to separate the left and right diffs?

Comment: @shmosel excatly. In the code above once the first content is printed it prints the next continuously. So finding it difficult to know where the second  one starts

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the map differences with a separation between the left and right sides, you can get them separately from the [`MapDifference`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html) result:

```
MapDifference diff = Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap);
bw.write("Only on left: " + diff.entriesOnlyOnLeft());
// add separation
bw.write("Only on right: " + diff.entriesOnlyOnRight());
```

To include the value differences:

```
bw.write("Value differences: " + diff.entriesDiffering());
```

Comment: i tried the above code but my file is empty ie there are no differences value in the file

Comment: Make sure you open the file first.

Comment: MapDifference has values but diff.entriesOnlyOnLeft() and diff.entriesOnlyOnRight() prints empty string

Comment: Then I guess there are no differences on the right.

Comment: nope there are differences as while i print the diff alone in sysout it displays the differences. does the entriesOnlyOnLeft() and entriesOnlyOnRight() has any rule? or condition

Comment: @Calvin It would help if you showed your current output to compare against.

Comment: @Calvin I added in the value diff, which I overlooked previously. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes after getting the difference diff.entriesDiffering() how to seperate them is my question

Comment: Ah, you want to separate each set of values?

Comment: yes.. like the differences in first file should come first and have some spaces and the difference in second should. These difference i need to print in a seperate file

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense to me. If you can include some sample input, output and expected output, I'll see if I can help you further.

Comment: @Calvin Please show how you would like it formatted. FYI, you should have enough info to figure the rest out.